# A package's testthat test requires the package itself to be installed. Is that bad?

Tags: r, devtools, cran, r-package, testthat

I just found out that one of the `testthat` unit tests in [drake](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake) fails if [drake](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake) is not actually installed first. (There is a test for which `devtools::load_all()` is not good enough.) I have since fixed this issue in the upstream closed-source repo, but in the meantime, before I can submit another [CRAN release](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=drake), how concerned should I be? All the CRAN checks passed before, and the [latest checks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_drake.html) for the new patch (2.1.1) are still passing. But if the CRAN maintainers decide to test packages before installation anytime soon, I will be in trouble.

More importantly, is there a slick way to test a package assuming the package itself is not already installed? Should there be? I usually forget to uninstall the package I am working on before a rigorous round of testing, it is annoying to have to uninstall and reinstall it every time, and it would be bad form to wrap my testing code with `remove.packages()` and `install_local()`.